# how to implement material outlined Textfield with trailing icon in Xamarin. Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, textfield

I have been trying to implement material visual for my app in Xamarin Forms. Right now i am focusing on outlined textfield with trailing icon. I have looked into customrenderer, but could not find any answer in Xamarin documentation, forums or any nuget package. 
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

#### Desired Result

[image: Desired Result]

As seen on material website: https://material.io/components/text-fields

Comment: I have created them on my own entirely on XF, without custom renderers, you could try to do it yourself or ask me and I share the code with you

Comment: thank you. i have added a picture in my answer of what i am trying to do. could you please share your code?

Comment: You could check the below codes and link and if Iyou accept third-party libraries, you can look at [XF-Material-Library](https://github.com/Baseflow/XF-Material-Library)

Comment: I have checked below code and the question that you mentioned. i also want the implementation in iOS. Your answer and the link does not mention iOS. and XF-material is currently handling leading icon, not trailing.

Comment: Th problem is also whole thing can not trigger any onClick. do you solve your issue?

Comment: @Mahdi sorry unfortunately no. I had to forgo this design and go with what the current design offered by Xamarin visual material.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CustomRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/introduction) to achieve it,you could refer to the [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59279947/10768653)

If you want to add a trailing icon,you just need add `android:drawableEnd` to the `EditText`,like :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Label"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/tab_about"//add a trailing icon
        android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MaterialDesignControlsPlugin](https://github.com/HorusSoftwareUY/MaterialDesignControlsPlugin)  it has [`TrailingIcon`](https://github.com/HorusSoftwareUY/MaterialDesignControlsPlugin/blob/master/src/MaterialDesignControls/Controls/MaterialEntry.xaml.cs#L319) with [`Outlined`](https://github.com/HorusSoftwareUY/MaterialDesignControlsPlugin/blob/master/src/MaterialDesignControls/Controls/MaterialEntry.xaml.cs#L440) properties

[image: sample]