# Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material Outlined Text fields

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, material-design, xamarin.forms.entry

is any possibility to use `Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material` NuGet package and set Text Fields style from `Filled` to `Outlined` without any custom renders for both platforms.

We already had it in `Xamarin.Android` only, but do we have it in `Xamarin.Forms` ???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently `Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material`package only supports **Android** and **iOS** .

The process for enabling Xamarin.Forms Material Visual in your application is:

1. Add the Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material NuGet package to your iOS and Android platform projects.(no need to install in Forms)
2. Initialize Material Visual in each platform project.

   - Android: Add in MainActivity.cs

     ```
     global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
     global::Xamarin.Forms.FormsMaterial.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
     ```
   - iOS: Add in AppDelegate

     ```
     global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
     global::Xamarin.Forms.FormsMaterial.Init();
     ```
3. Create Material Visual controls by setting the Visual property to **Material** on any pages that should adopt the Material Design rules.

---

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual/material-visual

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it will be `Filled` Style of Material in your example, I would like to achieve `Outlined` style and don't know(can't find) how to enable it 

Comment: Could you post the code how you achieve it in android ? Maybe you could implement this using custom renderer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual/material-visual#customize-material-visual.

Comment: As a reference, you can check these links: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61372298/how-to-implement-material-outlined-textfield-with-trailing-icon-in-xamarin-form
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62471816/outlined-material-entry-for-xamarin-forms-for-android-and-ios-both
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59132739/outlined-textbox-in-xamarin-
forms/59279947#59279947
And now comes my question, co we have it without  custom renderes, set by some flag, option or something like that

Comment: No , the package don't provide exact api to change control's style , i think the only solution is custom renderer (all the link you provided used custom renderer).