# Outlined Material Entry for Xamarin forms for Android and iOS both

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, material-design

How to create a outlined material entry in Xamarin forms for both Android and iOS using custom renderer?
e.g [Outlined Material Textfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxI0F.png)

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more detail of what you're trying to achieve here, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO !

You can use [Custom Renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view) to custom a View which contained a material designed `Entry` .

Create a **EntryView** in Forms:

```
public class EntryView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create("Text", typeof(string), typeof(EntryView), null);
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

About **Android** , then create the **EntryViewRenderer** :

```
public class EntryViewRenderer : ViewRenderer
{
    global::Android.Views.View view;
    global::Android.Widget.EditText editText;
    EntryView entryView;
    Activity activity;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if(e.NewElement != null)
        {
            entryView= e.NewElement as EntryView;
        }

        if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            SetupUserInterface();
            SetupEventHandlers();
            AddView(view);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"           ERROR: ", ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void SetupEventHandlers()
    {
        editText.TextChanged += EditText_TextChanged;
    }

    private void EditText_TextChanged(object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        entryView.Text = editText.Text; 
        Console.WriteLine("chanegd +" + entryView.Text);
    }

    void SetupUserInterface()
    {
        activity = this.Context as Activity;
        view = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.EntryLayout, this, false);

        editText = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

        var msw = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(r - l, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
        var msh = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(b - t, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);

        view.Measure(msw, msh);
        view.Layout(0, 0, r - l, b - t);
    }
}
```

In addition , you need to add **EntryLayout** for this View :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Label"
            android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now , you can use it in `Xaml` of Xamarin Forms :

```
xmlns:app18="clr-namespace:App18"

<app18:EntryView Text="abc"/>
```

The effect :

[image]

More info can refer to this dicsussion : [Outlined Textbox in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59132739/outlined-textbox-in-xamarin-forms/59279947#59279947)

**However** , about **iOS** , haven't found a way to achieve that by Custom Renderer .

**In addition** , there is a paid Nuget Packages `SfTextInputLayout` can achieve that in both Andoird and iOS platforms . Also can have a look at [that](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/text-input-layout/container-type?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#customize-the-corner-radius-of-the-outline-border) .